# There is any way to iterate over an outbound-gateway on based spring integration application?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway
            url="${xxx.smartbrain.produto}?startDate={dtInitPosicao}&amp;endDate={dtEnndPosicao}&amp;page=1&amp;recordPerPage=15&amp;cblc={cblc}&amp;cpfCnpj={cpf}"
            http-method="GET"
            expected-response-type="br.com.bradesco.ciar.xxx.xxx.xxx.integration.response.ResponseTesouroXXXXX"
            request-channel="publishSubRequest"
            reply-channel="agora-consolidador-splitter-xxxxx-direto-xxxx"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, cpf, cblc, dtInitPosicao">
        <int-http:uri-variable name="cpf" expression="headers.cpf"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="cblc" expression="headers.cblc"/>
        <int-http:uri-variable name="dtInitPosicao" expression="headers.dtinitposicao"/>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:splitter input-channel="agora-consolidador-splitter-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
                  output-channel="channelDirectRequestSmartBrainTesouroDireto">
        <bean class="br.com.bradesco.ciar.xxx.xxx.xxx.integration.splitter.TesouroDiretoMovimentacaoSplitter"/>
    </int:splitter>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="channelDirectRequestSmartBrainXXXXX" header-name="type" order="1">
        <int:mapping value="ativos" channel="requestAtivoXXXX"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="channelDirectRequestSmartBrainXXXXX" header-name="type" order="2">
        <int:mapping value="posicao" channel="requestMovimentoXXXXX"/>
    </int:header-value-router>

    <int:header-value-router input-channel="channelDirectRequestSmartBrainXXXXX" header-name="type" order="3">
        <int:mapping value="notifica" channel="notificacaoMovimentoXXXXX"/>
    </int:header-value-router>


    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${smartbrain.ativos}"
            channel="requestAtivoXXXXXX"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${smartbrain.xxxxxx}"
            channel="requestXXXXXXXX"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-http:outbound-channel-adapter
            http-method="POST"
            url="${smartbrain.notifica}"
            channel="notificacaoXXXXXXX"
            rest-template="restTemplate"
            mapped-request-headers="Authorization, DESTINO_URL">
    </int-http:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I'm consuming the information from the api above, but if I don't paginate to break the response in minor blocks the response is huge and take a long time to process. I'm trying to find a way to iterate over this outbound-gateway component. I'm not sure if I can do it using a router component is possible the create de mechanism that I need.

Based on the amount of pages, I have to call all of them iteratively.

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is correct in regards carrying page info in the headers.

And idea about a router is also correct. So, when you reach the router you make a decision to go ahead or come back to the `publishSubRequest` channel, but with a new page number.

It is not clear by your description what you are going to to with the current page, but in any case the `publish-subscribe-channel` as an output of this HTTP gateway (in your case `agora-consolidador-splitter-tesouro-direto-movimentacao`) is the way to go. So, you will be able to send the current page for processing downstream (e.g. store it in the aggregator until all the pages are gathered), and at the same time send the result info into the router to determine if you need to iterate back to the HTTP gateway or not. Well, the `<filter>` also can do you a trick over here since it doesn't look like you need to do anything if pages are exhausted. Still, the crucial part is to have a `publish-subscribe-channel` with two subscribers: one to process the current page and another to decide if you need to call for the next page.

Comment: In this case ... the response that comes from the outbound-gateway I send to the splitter because I have to create 3 different objects and send them to a third part app .. so each time that this outbound-gateway is called I have this flow to send the information to this external app. In this case I don't need to aggregate I just have to get the response and transform it to the object that the third part app is expecting.

Comment: I was think about your explanation and trying to visualize how this mechanic will work in my implementation, being honest  I can't see how to integrate the route between the outbound-gateway and the splitter to make it iterative.

Comment: I just add the entire flow to clarify what I just said

Comment: That input channel for splitter has to be a publish-subscribe-channel , so you will be able to attach one more subscriber for that router